# Should the ASP.NET Login and Shared Views be Removed when Using AngularJS?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have reviewed a number of code samples that use ASP.NET MVC 5, EF, and AngularJS.  Depending on the age of the code, I've seen examples that include the Shared views such as index.cshtml and I've also seen examples that run index.html instead.

In my application, I need to authenticate users via access token into our Web API 2 and use third party social logins as well.  Given the need to interact with ASP.NET Identity to handle logins, can the boilerplate ASP.NET Shared Views be jettisoned?  Should the boilerplate Account Views also be deleted as well?  Finally, I defined a WelcomeController to be used for the home page as follows:

```
function WelcomeController($scope, $location, authService, ngAuthSettings){
  var vm = this;
  activate();

  function activate() { }
}
```

I am calling it from index.cshtml as follows:

```
<body class="container">
<div data-ng-controller="WelcomeController" id="home">
    <div ng-include="~/Scripts/app/appnav.html"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div data-ng-view="">
            <div ng-include="~/Scripts/app/login.html"></div>
            <div ng-include="~/Scripts/app/signup.html"></div>
            <div ng-include="~/Scripts/app/welcome.html"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

When I run the [application](http://mfeweb.azurewebsites.net), a blank page is loaded in my browser after Facebook authentication with error stating:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod]
```

My app.js file contains the following:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'app.video','app.applications', 'app.login', 'app.signup']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/welcome', {
        templateUrl: 'app/welcome.html',
        controller: 'WelcomeController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        caseInsensitiveMatch: true
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/applications', {
        templateUrl: 'app/applications/application.html',
        controller: 'ApplicationsController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        caseInsensitiveMatch: true
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/video', {
        templateUrl: 'app/video/videos.html',
        controller: 'VideoController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        caseInsensitiveMatch: true
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        controller: 'LoginController',
        templateUrl: 'app/login.html'
    });

    $routProivder.when('/signup', {
        controller: 'SignUpController',
        templateUrl: 'app/signup.html'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/refresh', {
        controller: 'RefreshController',
        tempalateUrl: 'app/refresh.html'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/token', {
        controller: 'TokenManagerController',
        templateUrl: 'app/token.html'
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/welcome'
    });
}]);

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService');
});
```

I think the root cause is the Angular IndexController either is not configured correctly or the ASP.NET MVC login code is causing conflicts.  Need some guidance as to best resolution, and code samples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Judging by the error message, I'd say one of your app dependencies could not be found (maybe it's not part of your JS bundle or something). I could not check because I could not pass the registration process (datetime conversion error - MVC side). Could you disable authentication or provide a valid username and password? On a sidenote, your password requirements made it really hard for me to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the minified Angular with the unminified one, it says:

[image]

And this is because the function in `app.js` defining `angular.module('app', [])` is not invoked (in-place) at all (can be seen in the code).

There are also other issues: the minified JavaScript for Angular contains error messages about minification having failed and Angular has been included twice.